# Prefix for autogenerated alias on hibernate5

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, ucanaccess

I'm facing an issue with the aliases generated by Hibernate based on an Entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Base de Clientes")
public class BaseDeClientes{
    @Column(name="1011 Piso")
    private String _1011Piso;

    @Column(name="1011 Status")
    private String _1011Status;

    @Column(name="1011 Hasta")
    private Date _1011Hasta;

    @Column(name="1011 Observ")
    private String _1011Observ;

    @Column(name="Actuación")
    private long _actuacion;

    @Column(name="Año2")
    private long _anio2;

    @Column(name="MontoPN")
    private long montoPN;

    ... A LOT more...
}
```

And Hibernate generates a query like this one:

```
select
    this_.[Cod] as Cod1_0_0_,
    this_.[1011 Hasta] as column2_0_0_,
    this_.[1011 Observ] as column3_0_0_,
    this_.[1011 Piso] as column4_0_0_,
    this_.[1011 Status] as column5_0_0_,
    this_.[3r Piso] as column6_0_0_,
    this_.[4o Piso] as column7_0_0_,
    this_.[Actuación] as Actuació8_0_0_
from
    [Base de Clientes] this_ 
where
    this_.[Cod]=?
```

The problem is this (column `Actuació8_0_0_` not found):

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.0 Columna no encontrada: Actuació8_0_0_
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessResultSet.getLong(UcanaccessResultSet.java:471)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2738)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1729)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1655)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1544)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:727)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1774)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:385)
    at org.jotapdiez.asintra.dao.ClienteDaoImpl.getByCod(ClienteDaoImpl.java:32)
    at org.jotapdiez.asintra.service.access.AccessServiceImpl.byCod(AccessServiceImpl.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.byCod(Unknown Source)
    at org.jotapdiez.asintra.service.access.TestApplication.main(TestApplication.java:25)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Columna no encontrada: Actuació8_0_0_
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCResultSet.findColumn(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCResultSet.getLong(Unknown Source)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessResultSet.getLong(UcanaccessResultSet.java:469)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Columna no encontrada: Actuació8_0_0_
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

I think that is because the accent and other characters and I can't change anything from that database.

In the query some fields are generated with alias like `columnXX_0_0_` (because start with numbers?) and others with a portion of the string from the field name.

**I there any way to prefix the alias creation or change to be always like `columnXX_X_X_`?**

I tried a lot with `ImplicitNamingStrategy` and `PhysicalNamingStrategy` but I can't make it works.

Comment: I have reproduced the issue under UCanAccess 4.0.1 using plain JDBC. It has been escalated and should be fixed in the next release of UCanAccess.

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks you. I tried to solve it on the wrong way. But, I think that hibernate should provide a way to modify the aliases.

Comment: @GordThompson Is there any plan to release a new version? Or a fix for this? Thanks

Comment: This issue has been resolved in UCanAccess version 4.0.2.